Can Power BI be used to implement an alternate product recommender
We have an excel containing a list of products and their stocks supply. Suppose a customer places an order for product A, but product A happens to be out of stock.  Maintained in the excel are alternate products to product A, such as product B, product C, etc.
Can a power bi solution be implemented
to automate this, and if so, how?
(Please provide details)

I don't think we can let user to type in the order and get the calculation result. However, if you can provide the demand amount , we can calculate if stock of product A is available or not
